# Does a lamp need a fuse?

Tags: safety, fuses, lamp

I have a floor lamp in which I have installed 2 LIFX Color 1000 A19 Wi-Fi LED Smart Bulbs (http://www.lifx.com/products/color-1000)

The lamp is designed to have 2 bulbs and has a two position dimmer switch for the bulbs wired in parallel so that in position 1, both bulbs light at 50%, and at position 2, both bulbs light at 100%.

The problem is, the smart bulbs do not work with the dimmer switch (they lose the wifi connection intermittently) so I would like to remove the dimmer switch.

The dimmer switch is wired such that it has one wire going into it, and one wire leaving it. The easiest thing I can do is to cut the wires on either side of the dimmer and connect them together, therefore bypassing the switch altogether.

The only thing is that there is a 3A fuse in the switch.  Is this needed?  Or is my solution ok (bypass the switch and fuse altogether).

I live in the United States.

Comment: The bulbs will probably burn faster than the fuse, so I think it is useless..

Comment: Are you sure that it's a dimmer or does the switch connect the lamps in series?

Comment: No, but fusing of bulbs has an interesting history. Slightly off topic but check out the high speed videos of real Osram versus Chinese G9 halogen bulbs. One has a working built in fuse, the other something which looks like a fuse. http://www.lamptech.co.uk/Movies.htm

Comment: This is a CIRCUIT DESIGN question which seems EXACTLY on-topic for this forum.  This is NOT a "use of device" question. The question is about re-designing the original circuit. I disagree with the people who put this question on hold.

Answer (score 6):

No. It seems very unlikely there is any need for a fuse. The LIFX gadgets are presumed to be rated for direct connection to a mains branch circuit without any additional fusing.  The fuse was probably there to protect the switch as incandescent lamps do not require fusing. They act as their own fuse.

The "dimming" feature where it connected two bulbs in series is only valid for the original incandescent bulbs. It is virtually guaranteed to NOT work with any other kind of bulb, and especially not something like the LIFX.  You are quite right to remove this obsolete "feature".

Answer (score 0):

Incandesent lamps with coiled tungsten filaments can fail in a mode where the now open ends can touch a different mechanical part of the internal parts of the lamp, and in effect create a new much higher current, much lower resistance circuit. A fuse installed would blow to protect it's environment. The Smart, WiFi controlled LED lamp would/should not fail in such a way.